# Avoiding null or empty values to save in database using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, null, asp.net-ajax, save

I have an application where we are using entity framework and on button click an ajax call is made to save values.
Everything is working fine, but even if we try to click the save button, with no values, it gets saved in database as null or empty(takes space).
There is some minor error which I am overlooking, please help me out.
What I tried:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '~/SaveGroups',
            data: {
            GroupId: (GroupId == null ? -1 : GroupId),
            counterId: (counterId == null ? -1 : counterId),
            GroupCode: GroupCode,
            GroupDesc: GroupDescription
        },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    $("#PartialGroupsTable").html(result.GroupsPageString);
                    $("#GCode").val('')             //GCode is the name of the textbox
                    $("#GDescription").val('');     //GDescription is the other textbox
                    GroupId = -1;
        }

        },
            complete: function () {
                $("#GCode").empty();
                $("#GDescription").empty();
        },
            error: function () {
                alert("Details Not Saved. Please try again later");
        }

        });
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to phrase an actual question, please. What exactly are you trying to do? Disallow saving if values are not filled in? What's not working? What's the minor error? Do you want -1 to get in the database and it doesn't? Is this all to do with javascript or something else as well?

Comment: @AlexPaven, I want to save values which are entered in the textbox, and on click of the 'save' button, by an ajax call it saves.That part is working fine, values are getting saved. But if we enter nothing in the text-box, then it is saving the null or an empty string, which is the part, I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to fulfill your requirements, two of them are `Client Side validation and server side validations` that means you need to validate the data before send it to database for saving.. like

you have model classes right.. that represent your tables

```
public class User
{
[Required]
public string UserName{get; set;}
...
...
}
```

suppose if you try to send null values to controllers or dbcontext it wont allows you to insert null values into it since it allows only non-null values.

and also you can do this as well using jquery

```
function buttonClick()
{
if($('#txtName').val()=='')
{
alert('Please enter name');
return false;
}
else
{
//make ajax call here
}
}
```

like this you can do it in many ways you can use unobtrusive javascript as well. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanx for your help, @Karthik Bammidi : Let me see if that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect to get -1 for GroupId or counterId and instead get something else, the reason is probably that the existing value is not null but perhaps an empty string. Check for that as well as checking for null/undefined. If that's not the problem then additional information may be needed.

For example:

```
GroupId: ((GroupId == null || GroupId == '') ? -1 : GroupId),
```